# ui-view is calling multiple times when another template is binding as child view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

what iam trying is to get the child views for different states

### my states code

```
 routeConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

  function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'          
      }).state('home.companies.products',{
        abstract: true,
        url: 'companies',
        views: {
          'allcompanies@home': {
            templateUrl: 'companiesList.html',
            controller: 'CompanyController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
          }
        }
      }).state('home.companies.products.detail', {
      url: '/:companyId',
      views: {
        'single-company': {
          templateUrl: 'single-company.html',
          controller: 'SingleCompanyController',
          controllerAs: 'vm',
          resolve: {
            companyResolve: getCompany
          }
        }
      }
    });
}
```

### home.html

```
<div ui-view="allcompanies">
<h2>Home template</h2>
</div>
```

### companiesList.html

```
<div ui-view="single-company">
<div ng-init="someFunc()">
<h2>Companies List</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

### single-company.html

```
<div>
<h2> single company </h2>
</div>
```

my problem is when i call the "home.companies.products.detail" state it will bind in the ui-view="single-company" template instead of companies list while "single-company" is binding on "companies List" the init function is calling in the background i dont need to call that function bcz of that the function is calling twice if i again go to "allcompanies" view again the function is calling third time so iam getting the issues when again and again the init function is calling so how can manage the child states without calling that function again and again

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ng-init. According to angularjs documentation:

> There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope. 
>   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

If the purpose of `ng-init="someFunc()"` is to be executed only once when Companies list is loaded in the beginning, then call the function inside CompanyController. It will execute the first time the controller is created.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have wrapped your controller in an anonymous function like below:

```
(function() {
angular.module('example', []){
someFunc(); //Function call

//Add function declaration here

});
```

Then the function will be executed when the controller is created. If you remove the ng-init directive and place the function here this would solve your issue and would be better practice according to the angular documentation.

Hope that helps.